# Java Telegram Bot: Numeric value out of range of int

Tags: java, bots, telegram

A few years ago, I created two bots, using telegrambots-3.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.

My bots extend the class `TelegramLongPollingBot`.

Both of them, now, suffer the very same problem.
Every time that a user with user_ID>2147483647 joins the group, the bots stop working for several days, reporting continuously the following error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (5042963863) out of range of int
 at [Source: {"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":412942830,
"message":{"message_id":306587,"from":{"id":5042963863,"is_bot"
```

I've tried to use a newer version of libraries (telegrambots-5.1.1-jar-with-dependencies), but in this case, I get many compilation errors, because of missing types (many `import`s don't work anymore).

I've also tried to use Webhook, but I can't find a complete example that explains how to use the Webhook variable after having set it.
This wouldn't solve the 'out of range error', but at least the bot would still remain active (while now with PollingBot, the bot remains in error-state for many days: even after having shut it down and turned it on again, the bot doesn't work).

Comment: don't use int, use long instead

Comment: @Stultuske I suspect that the `int` is defined in a class in the library, so changing it is a mess.

Comment: 3.6.1 seems to be from 2018, so you might want to update anyways. Your current code is trying to convert a number to an `int`, which is probably defined in some jackson-annotated class in the telegrambots library. As Stultuske mentioned, this needs to be changed to a long, which might be out of your control.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's out of my control. I Think that variable is defined on BeanDeserializer.java,but I don't have access to that file. So I would like to update my 3.6.1 version, but if I do it, many import stop to work and I dont understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced that issued. But I'm not sure you're using rubenlagus telegram bot library or not. If you use may it's old version of telegram bot. Just update to latest telegram bot.
https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/issues/1017#issuecomment-1143168283

There are some change on version from lower version. Read more on https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/How-To-Update

Comment: Hello, thanks you for your answer. I'm using rubelangus telegram bot library, and I already tried to update to from version 3.6.1 to telegrambots-5.1.1-jar-with-dependencies, but as I've explained in my original post, if I do that, almost every 'import' stop to work. For every 'import' line, I will get the following error: "the import ... can't be resolved", so I don't understand how to update correctly the version of the telegram bot...

Comment: Hello, I think you moved from version 3.6.1 to 5.1.1 there're a lot of changes. You should move to latest version (6.0.1) and keep practicing the example on the link above. You'll understand the flow, then you can change your code step by step. Telegram bot old version will not response on user_id of new telegram api 2.0. So I think there's only way keep learning bro. You can do it by step. :)

Comment: Hello, thanks you very much. Finally I got some time to do it and it worked, but now I've another problem and it is about the sendPhoto() method which doesn't accept the string parameter anymore. Anyway I think I've to open another thread for that...

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem about sendPhoto() error. Further you can read this tuturial (https://monsterdeveloper.gitbooks.io/writing-telegram-bots-on-java/content/lesson-2.-photobot.html). For new versions, you can read from rubenlagus repo.

Comment: I solved My problem. I had to use FileInput as parameter of setPhoto(FileInput) and file_id had to be the parameter of FileInput(file_id) constructor. Now Everything works. Thanks you very much for your time :)