# Java Telegram Bot: how to send photos having their file_id?

Tags: java, api, bots, telegram

A few years ago I created a bot with *telegrambots* version 3.6.1.
Unfortunately there was a problem: every time that a user with user_ID>2147483647 joined the group, the bot crashed, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593707/java-telegram-bot-numeric-value-out-of-range-of-int).

I've just found out how to update the version of *telegrambots*, but now I've another problem.

I need to use the setPhoto(String file_id) method as described [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) in Telegram ot JAVA API page (Pass a file_id as String to send a photo that exists on the Telegram servers).

It looks like that method doesn't accept String parameter anymore since *telegrambots* version [5.0.0](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.telegram/telegrambots-meta/5.0.0/org/telegram/telegrambots/meta/api/methods/send/SendPhoto.html).

Infact it worked until *telegrambots* version [4.9.2](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.telegram/telegrambots-meta/4.9.2/org/telegram/telegrambots/meta/api/methods/send/SendPhoto.html).

So my bot pins a message in the group with a list of many places, each one can have up till 2 photos.
Each of these photos has its file_id saved in a field of a MySql database.

So basically when we use the command to see a pic associated to a place, my code uses setPhoto(file_id) getting the file_id string from the database.

Now it looks like setPhoto(String) doesn't work anymore, so how can I solve this problem? I still need to use all the photo we saved in those years. How can i convert these file_id into InputFile argument?

I've tried to use version 4.9.2 of *telegrambots* and setPhoto(String) works, but I don't know if in that version, my original problem (numeric value out of range) was already solved and anyway I would like to use the latest version (6.4.0).

I've no idea how to convert String (fileID from database) to InputFile.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is not really documenting anything, but it looks like the [`FileInput` constructor](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.telegram/telegrambots-meta/5.0.0/org/telegram/telegrambots/meta/api/objects/InputFile.html) can take `String` called attach(ement).

Comment: Yes, it worked. I had to use setPhoto(FileInput) and file_id has to be the String parameter of FileInput constructor. Thanks you very much.